# Encountering INET framework error in OMNeT++ 5.7. Need help troubleshooting the issue

Tags: openstreetmap, omnet++, veins, sumo, inet

inet problem

[image]

I have tried simulating in 6.0.1 there is a problem of veins library, after that I downloaded the older version 5.7, now the problem is on inet during building project.

Any suggestions or debugging strategies?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, you are trying to installing INET 4.4 or 4.5 and that version requires OMNeT++ 6.0. so using older version of omnet will not work.